# Child handles of vbox Windows using Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, virtualbox, children, handle

I want to get all of children handle of Windows that its run in Virtual Box . 
I want send a key from Host Windows(Main Windows) to notepad of Guest Windows.
I know that we can find child window by using **EnumChildWindows** in *delphi* but Virtual Box only retrieve **QWidget** class name.
can anyone help me access to all of handle of Guest Windows(its run in Virtual Box) from main windows using *delphi* ? 
thank you.

Comment: From the perspective of the host virtual box is effectively showing you a picture of another operating system drawn on a QWidget.  You would need to run your code inside the VM.

Comment: I thought before like your answer but windows has a On-Screen Keyboard that we can use it in the Main windows and type anything and see that in guest windows(in virtual box).

Comment: You cannot target a window inside the VM from outside the VM. A google search for VirtualBox send keystrokes does not yield very much. I second @AlexK.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that VirtualBox has a keyboard driver interfacing with the host and it knows which guest window is in the foreground. That has nothing to do with the fact that the guest window have no child windows as far as the host is concerned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to get all of children handle of Windows that its run in Virtual Box .

Sorry, but you cannot do that.  Like AlexK said in comments, windows running within the guest OS simply do not exist within the host OS, so they cannot be accessed or enumerated by apps running in the host OS.  The VM is running a completely separate guest OS and is simply rendering the display output of that OS on its own window running on the host OS.

> I want send a key from Host Windows(Main Windows) to notepad of Guest Windows.

There is no way to do that *directly*.

When a user types a key on the physical keyboard or an on-screen keyboard within the host OS, the key is put into the input queue of the host OS and gets routed to the current focused window within the host OS.  If that window happens to be the VM, then the VM places the key in the input queue of the guest OS and it gets routed to the current focused window within the guest OS.

An app running on the host OS can use `SendInput()` to simulate keyboard input in the host OS, and let it get routed accordingly.

If you need more control, you will have to run a separate app within the guest OS that is connected to your main app running on the host OS.  The host app can then communicate with the guest app, and the guest app can act on guest windows as needed.

For example, the host app could ask the guest app to enumerate the guest windows and send that list back to the host app.  The host app could detect the presence of Notepad and send the desired key(s) to the guest app, which could then send the key(s) to the Notepad window.

> I know that we can find child window by using EnumChildWindows in delphi

Only for windows that are running in the same OS that the enumerating app is running in.

> but Virtual Box only retrieve QWidget class name.

Because that is the window that is running within the host OS.

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply.You know that we can type by On-Screen Keyboard 
in host OS and see that in guest OS without any app that we need to have use inside guest OS.
I think that host OS by using On-Screen Keyboard send virtual keys to guest OS directly.
But i dont know how to do that.

Comment: @M.MARAMI read my answer again more carefully, I covered that exact scenario. The OSK *does not* send the keys directly to the guest OS. It has no concept of VMs. It puts keys into the host's input queue and they get routed through normal dispatching into the VM's window and then the VM copies them into the guest's input queue. `SendInput()` is the way to handle that initial send.

Comment: Its ok. Can you bring an example for SendInput().I search and found some example but cant do it anymore.
Because none of those examples were not associated with our work.

Comment: @M.MARAMI there are like a bazillion examples of `SendInput()` in various languages, including Delphi. If you are having trouble with it, post a new question and show your code. This question has been answered as asked (enumerating windows inside a VM is not possible without a helper app running inside the guest OS. Sending keyboard input to a VM is handled the same way as with any other app, using `SendInput()`).